# Ask about past time

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

Is the question right or wrong? If wrong, please how can I ask about how long they haven't seen each other im the past.

Q: How long have you hadn't seen each other?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that SovereignSun's answers come across as rather awkward English, I can't imagine either being used in normal speech (written or spoken). Personally, I would reorder things a little and say:

> How long has it been since you last saw each other?

or

> When was the last time you saw each other?

Answer (score 0):

No, your question isn't correct.

- How long have you not seen each other? *(colloquial, non-idiomatic)*
- How long haven't you seen each other? *(colloquial, non-idiomatic)*

In terms of natural English the present perfect in negative sentences sounds okay mostly in progressive constructions. @Solarflare's options "*How long has it been since you last saw each other?*" and "*When was the last time you saw each other?*" are the ways most native speaker would say it.

***Remark***: I didn't place emphasis on what sounds natural in the first place, only on the constructed sentence from the point of view of grammar.